Significance testing of % change between two dates of a group compared to total population
I want to calculate whether the reduction or increase of each individual groups % change is significantly different than the total reduction or increase for the entire population. For example, if I have six schools with different known populations. I have calculated the rate of teachers per 10000 population over two dates. I want to know if the change in % for each group is significantly different than the % change across all schools. Here is my data
enter image description here
I have tried Z test for two proportions, however I do not think this is correct as my proportion I am interested in is the % change.
I am using Microsoft excel.
Any help is much appreciated.

This appears to be more of a question about statistics than Excel per se.
